# using an external script page for my page which needs multiple scripts

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, onclick

I am currently making a page for educational purposes. Now i am making a page which contains multiple buttons that contain the function that when u click them, that they will play music. now i need 10 of these under eachother. But I have 10 different sound fragments. If i put 10 different scripts underneath eachother, that will make an absolute mess and I was wondering if it was possible to have those scripts together in an other file. Or is there an easier way to do it? I have this idea that this can be a lot easier.

this is the script and html I use.

```
    <script>

        function playMusic (){
            var audio = document.getElementById("geluidsopname");
            audio.play();   
        }
    </script>   

         <button id="voortgang-button" onclick="playMusic()" value="button">    
         <img id="afspeelbutton"   src ="../../../image/afspeelbutton1.png">                    </img>Ik heet Marie.    
         <audio id="geluidsopname" src="../../../voice-recording/Marie.mp3"></audio>
    </button>
```

Comment: You mean this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp

Comment: In any case, you can generalize your script to take a parameter, so that you can do something like this: onclick="playMusic('my_audio_id')", and only 1 copy of script will be needed then.

Comment: @vladimirM sounds interesting! can you explain that some more? couldnt i also use onclick="playMusic(my source)" so it calls out to the script, and then the script will get the source for the music from my onclick? is that what you mean? and I am pretty new when it comes to java, is there a possibilty you could help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to assign every element a unique `id`, you can access them through different methods. Take a look at [document.querySelector](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp), for example.

Calling a JS function from within an HTML event attribute is *fine*, but not recommended. Registering an event directly on your JS code is much cleaner.

You may want to put a single script just before the `body`'s closure, or eventually put it in the `head` and execute it on `DOMContentLoaded`.

```
<button class="myBtn" id="button1">
  <img src="url">
  <audio>
    <source src="url" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio feature.
  </audio>
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  for (var aud in document.querySelectorAll('.myBtn')) {
      aud.addEventListener('click', function() {
        aud.querySelector('audio').play();
      }, false);
  }
</script>
```

Of course, you could just add the `controls` attribute to the `audio` element and have all events related to audio controls handled by the browser:

```
<button class="myBtn">
  <img src="url">
  <audio controls>
    <source src="url" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio feature.
  </audio>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8GzuoI8ytRpYpv5rYhsb?p=info) of the code. I've modified a bit the html structure for the demo. Still the idea is there: your script uses parameter.

```
// Code goes here

     function playMusic ( target ){
        console.log(target.getAttribute("target_audio"))
        var audio = document.getElementById( target.getAttribute("target_audio") );
        audio.play();   
    }
```

And html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="button" id="voortgang-button" target_audio="geluidsopname" onclick="playMusic( this )" value="button">
    <img id="afspeelbutton"   src ="../../../image/afspeelbutton1.png">Ik heet Marie.    
    <audio id="geluidsopname" src="../../../voice-recording/Marie.mp3"></audio>

  </body>

</html>
```

If you like, you can pass id as a string, to the handler method. Then you dont need to get attribute's value even.